# How do I get a file name from DevOps artifact package - Azure

Tags: python, azure-devops

I need to download all afrtifacts from Azure DevOps repository.

If I know exact file name from the package I can use this API:

```
import requests, os
package_url = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myOrganization/_apis/packaging/feeds/myFeed/pypi/packages/myPackageName/versions/1.2.0.219/myFileName_with_version.whl/content?api-version=6.1-preview.1"
        
package_json = requests.get(package_url, auth=auth_tuple, allow_redirects=True).json()
        
open('myFileName_with_version.whl', 'wb').write(package_json.content)
```

But I got file name `myFileName_with_version.whl` from https://dev.azure.com/ UI and have no idea how to get using API.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get a file name from DevOps artifact package - Azure

We could use the REST API [Artifact Details - Get Package Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details/get%20package%20version?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
GET https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/Packages/{packageId}/versions/{packageVersionId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

to get the file name:

[image]

**Note:** To get the `{packageId}` and `{packageVersionId}`, we could use the REST API [Artifact Details - Get Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details/get%20packages?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

[image]